# "...saw that to begin with..." Meaning in this context

Tags: sentence-meaning

I am having difficulties making the sentence out:

> You all **saw that to begin** with the tape measure stretched across from one side to the other, exactly.

I know about the pattern **see someone do something** but not **see someone to do something.**

EDIT: https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/tape-measure

Please tell me the meaning.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide us with the source, please?

Comment: @AIQ Longman Dictionary under "tape measure"

Comment: Next time, you can add the link to your source just like I did in the edit. Also you wrote "saw **them** to" but in the dictionary its "saw **that** to".

Comment: @AIQ please explain the meaning.

Comment: I don't understand the sentence, it seems incomplete to me. You will have to wait to hear what others say.

Answer (score 2):

**To begin with** is a common expression meaning, in this context, *originally*. So your sentence means "You all saw that originally the tape-measure stretched across from one side to the other exactly." (The last comma isn't needed.) It might be re-ordered:

> Originally, as you all saw, the tape-measure stretched across from
>   one side to the other exactly.